# Unity Pass Raw Quaternion Radian Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am very new to Unity and have created a humanoid and written a script allowing you to pass Euler angles which is then converted into a Quaternion and then I use GetBoneTransform to move a particular bone.

I am passing data from sensors into unity which then maps my movement, when wearing the sensors unity tracks my movement in realtime and then animates the character on the screen.

Due to me using Euler angles I came across Gimble lock which is causing me a massive headache and has halted all my progress. The data I am passing from the sensors is Euler angle but I founf out I can get raw Quaternion (radian) data and was wondering how I could use this to prevent me from suffering from Gimble lock.

I have used this online conventer to try and get a better understanding of the Quarternion data I am receiving - https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/

The sensor is passing me wxyz data and when I input this data into the Quaternion section it is outputting the correct angle (x:0 y:0 z:166).

Does Unity have a way of passing wxyz radian data which I am only presuming will fix my Gimble lock issue.

Here is an example of my current code where I pass in Euler angle which then rotates the bone

```
public void offset(float x, float y, float z) {
    offset(Quaternion.Euler(x, y, z));
}

public void offset(Quaternion q) {
    Transform tr = animator.GetBoneTransform(bone);
    tr.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(tr.localRotation, q * savedValue, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
}
```

Comment: When you say "sensor data" are you referring to the gyroscope orientation of a phone?

Comment: Do you want to rotate based on the offset from the initial orientation?